# Unity3D - How to create a scene Holder for all levels and unlock some?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm new to unity and my programming capabitlities is still somewhat weak, I'm working on a 2d Platformer game as way to learn how to code meanwhile to practice my passion which is game development

my main issue right now is that I have two scenes(Level1,Level2) and then I have a SceneSelctor
in the Selector I got two doors represent both levels, but the probleme I'm facing is althought

> I created a little code to Lock the Level2 untill i reach a point and then unlock it,, is when I start the game the level2 is always unlocked which doesn't serves me well

the code that control this stuff is saved on two scripts 
I used Hastebin as I didn't know how to copy/paste the code in here

https://hastebin.com/oluzujukid.cs

===> LevelDoor.cs

```
public class LevelDoor : MonoBehaviour {

public string levelToLoad;

public bool unlocked;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

//first level must be always unlocked
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level1", 1);

//when the leveltoLoad = 1 that mean that the level should be unlocked
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(levelToLoad) == 1)
    {
        unlocked = true;
    } else
    {
        unlocked = false;
    }

//some animation stuff toshow doorOpen or closed
    if(unlocked)
    {
        doorTop.sprite = doorTopOpen;
        doorBottom.sprite = doorBottomOpen;
    } else
    {
        doorTop.sprite = doorTopClosed;
        doorBottom.sprite = doorBottomClosed;
    }
}
```

===> LevelExit.cs

```
public class LevelExit : MonoBehaviour {

public string levelToUnlock;
}


public IEnumerator levelExitCo()
{
    // if the player reach the checkpoint thisline unlock the second level on SceneSelect
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(levelToUnlock, 1);
}
```

Comment: You can paste the code here and then use formatting options: look for "{ }" icon.

Comment: yes i thought about it but i was getting some weird result like only a part of the scipt  highlited so i opted for hastebin

Comment: Paste it and do you best with formatting. Someone else will edit your question and fix it if not 100%. Better chance of getting an answer this way.

Comment: thnx for your feedback i edited the thread i think now it appears much better

Comment: Why no use a uint to control all locked status of all your door, and assign an  unique binary value to each door. 
With the binary value you got if the bit of the doorID is locked or unlocked.

Comment: i honestly don't know how to do that :) if you can be more specific i would appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this issue:

Once the door in unlock I would set a trigger (just behind the opened door) which will load a new scene. Then to move from one scene to another I would use

```
SceneManager.LoadScene()
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

In the second Level you can always place another door, already opened, with its trigger so the player can move back to the first level

Edit with another approach:

If you want to have a game with different levels that you can unlock sequentially, one thing you can do is to create a singleton variable, that is a unique variable that will be shared for all game scenes, of type array of booleans. Each element in the array will represent a level. Initially you can define all levels but the first one as false (so all locked) and when you consider a level can be unlocked you change that value

So at the beggining of your game you can call a scrip similar to (lets imagine you have 10 levels):

```
public static bool[] levels = new bool[10];
levels[0]=true
for (int i = 1; i < levels.Length; i++) 
{ levels[i] = false; }
```

Comment: i think you didn't get the problem i'm facing the doors already got a zone where you click "Jump" Button as the Trigger

the flow of my game is like this
When you reach a certain Checkpoint at the end of level 1, Level2 get unlocked and then you get directed to LevelSelector where there is two doors represents both levels and gives you the chance to replay level1 or move to level2 

***my problem is that i want level2 in LevelSelector locked by default which isn't right now***

Comment: i think i somehow know why i'm getting such problem is because for somereason my default setting for level2 is "1" so its get unlocked is there any way i can set it as "0" untill i unlockit by reaching the end of Level1

i would appreciate it if you have a teamviewer so you can help me